# Discord.py bot song queueing: voice_client.play() plays all loops at beginning

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I have a discord bot that allows the users to queue songs, here is a simplified version of the code:

```
class Music(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, bot: Bot, config: Dict[str, Any]):
      self.bot = bot
      self.queue = asyncio.Queue()
      self.urlqueue = list()
      self.yt_api = YoutubeAPI(config["YD_DL_OPTS"], DL_DIR)
      self.load_queue.start()

  @commands.command(name="play", aliases=["p"], pass_context=True, usage=DOCS_PLAY)
  async def play(self, ctx: Context, *args):
      if ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
          ctx.voice_client.stop()
      await self.play_song(ctx)

  @commands.command(name="queue", aliases=["q"], pass_context=True, usage=DOCS_QUEUE)
  async def queue(self, ctx: Context, *args):    
      self.urlqueue.append(args[0])

  @tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)
  async def load_queue(self):
      if len(self.urlqueue) == 0:
          return
      for track in self.yt_api.create_tracks(self.urlqueue.pop(0)):
          if self.yt_api.download_track(track):
              await self.queue.put(track)
              logger.info("queued track [{}]".format(track.title))

  async def play_song(self, ctx: Context):
      logger.info("getting track [{}]".format(track.title))
      track = await self.queue.get()
      logger.info("playing track [{}]".format(track.title))
      await ctx.send(content="playing track {}".format(track.title))
      ctx.voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(track.filename), after=await self.after(ctx))
      ctx.voice_client.is_playing()

  async def after(self, ctx):
      if not self.queue.empty() and not ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
          logger.info("looping start")
          await self.play_song(ctx)
          logger.info("looping end")

  def cog_unload(self):
      self.load_queue.cancel()
```

When urls are passed with the `queue` command, a track is created, downloaded and added to a `asyncio.Queue()` by the looping `load_queue()` method.

The issue occurs when the `play` command is called, in the method `play_song()` on the line `ctx.voice_client.play()` the `after` parameter is called immediately before the first track is even played. This leads to the method quickly looping through all the songs in the queue first and trying to play them all at once. In the end only the first song in the queue is actually played, since the other songs all hit a `ClientException('Already playing audio.')` exception. The log looks like this:

```
2021-06-18 10:38:09,004 | INFO     | 0033 | Bot online!
2021-06-18 10:38:23,442 | INFO     | 0222 | queued track [i miss you]
2021-06-18 10:38:26,882 | INFO     | 0222 | queued track [When you taste an energy drink for the first time]
2021-06-18 10:38:32,828 | INFO     | 0205 | joined General by request of Admin
2021-06-18 10:38:32,829 | INFO     | 0226 | got track [i miss you]
2021-06-18 10:38:32,829 | INFO     | 0230 | playing track [i miss you]
2021-06-18 10:38:32,832 | INFO     | 0236 | loop start
2021-06-18 10:38:32,832 | INFO     | 0226 | got track [When you taste an energy drink for the first time]
2021-06-18 10:38:32,833 | INFO     | 0230 | playing track [When you taste an energy drink for the first time]
2021-06-18 10:38:32,837 | INFO     | 0238 | loop end
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kenmu\Repos\DiscordBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kenmu\Repos\DiscordBot\music.py", line 91, in play
    await self.play_song(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\kenmu\Repos\DiscordBot\music.py", line 231, in play_song
    ctx.voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(track.filename), after=await self.after(ctx))
  File "C:\Users\kenmu\Repos\DiscordBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 558, in play
    raise ClientException('Already playing audio.')
discord.errors.ClientException: Already playing audio.
```

As you can see it tries to loop through the whole queue in a couple of milliseconds. I thought the `after` parameter is triggered after the song has finished playing? How would I get it to trigger after the song is finished? Is there a better way to handle a playing through a queue of songs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=play#discord.VoiceClient.play):

> The finalizer, after is called after the source has been exhausted or an error occurred.
>
> ...
>
> - after (Callable[[Exception], Any]) – The finalizer that is called after the stream is exhausted. This function must have a single parameter, error, that denotes an optional exception that was raised during playing.

You are calling `await self.after(ctx)` when you set the `after` parameter, which is before `ctx.voice_client.play` is even called. You need to provide it with a callable (e.g. a function) that takes the exception raised during playing, which defaults to `None` if no exception was raised.

Something like this:

```
    async def play_song(self, ctx: Context):
        logger.info("getting track [{}]".format(track.title))
        track = await self.queue.get()
        logger.info("playing track [{}]".format(track.title))
        await ctx.send(content="playing track {}".format(track.title))
        ctx.voice_client.play(
            discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(track.filename),
            after=lambda ex: asyncio.get_running_loop().create_task(self.after(ctx))
        )
        ctx.voice_client.is_playing()

    async def after(self, ctx):
        if not self.queue.empty() and not ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
            logger.info("looping start")
            await self.play_song(ctx)
            logger.info("looping end")
```

But you shouldn't be using the `after` parameter to play the next song in the queue. You can [see how it's done (with a while loop in the `player_loop` coroutine) here](https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/ab667b74e9758433b3eb806c53a19f34).

Comment: That makes sense, only I can't put an *await* inside a lambda or else I get the following error:
````
after=lambda ex: await self.after(ctx))
                     ^
SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function
```
Any idea how I could make it work?

Comment: @kmurrell I have updated the answer with code that should be able to run with your current design, but I wan to stress that this is not the proper way to handle a music queue with discord.py - the `after` parameter of is meant to handle exceptions that occur while playing, not schedule tasks.

Comment: Great answer, thanks for providing both a fix and a better solution!